# Flutter crashes when using AudioPlayers and Future.wait to play a list of sound effects simultaneously

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I'd like to create a list of `List<Future<void>>` that represent executions of sound effects.

I therefore iterate through a list of event types/formats (ie. "sword") and map each to a sound effect play execution.

I wrap these Futures in a `Future.delayed` for each with a random number of milliseconds from 30 to 100 just to have a little random occurance of when the sound effects are played in order (to add a pause between two sound effects).

The list of those sound effect Futures is then called by `Future.wait` where I expected the list to be resolved and the `Future.delay` might take effect.

This is my code

```dart
 _playActionEventSounds() async {
    if (widget.log.isNotEmpty) {
      final lastRound = widget.log.map((e) => e.round).reduce(max);
      final lastActionEvents = widget.log.where((actionEvent) => actionEvent.round == lastRound);
      final List<Future<void>> eventSounds = lastActionEvents.map((actionEvent) async {
        if (actionEvent.format == "sword") {
          return Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: next(30, 100)), () => _soundPlayer.punch());
        }
        if (actionEvent.format == "damage") {
          return Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: next(30, 100)), () => _soundPlayer.pain());
        }
        return Future.value(null);
      }).toList();

      await Future.wait(eventSounds);
    }
  }
```

SoundPlayer class:

```dart
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class SoundPlayer {
  Future<void> punch() async {
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    player.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.stop);
    return await player.play(AssetSource("sounds/punch.wav"));
  }

  Future<void> pain() async {
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    player.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.stop);
    return await player.play(AssetSource("sounds/pain.wav"));
  }
}
```

I now can run the process multiple times. I do hear the sounds appear as expected. But after the 4th execution the app crashes.

This is the error:

```
I/flutter (28346): Unexpected platform error: MediaPlayer error with what:MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN {what:1} extra:MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN {extra:-19}
E/MediaPlayerNative(28346): pause called in state 0, mPlayer(0xb400007a92646810)
E/MediaPlayerNative(28346): error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayerNative(28346): Attempt to call getDuration in wrong state: mPlayer=0xb400007a92646810, mCurrentState=0
E/MediaPlayerNative(28346): error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayerNative(28346): stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0xb400007a92646810)
E/MediaPlayerNative(28346): error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayerNative(28346): prepareAsync called in state 0, mPlayer(0xb400007a92646810)
D/AndroidRuntime(28346): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(28346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(28346): Process: com.example.app, PID: 28346
E/AndroidRuntime(28346): java.lang.IllegalStateException
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1313)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.MediaPlayerPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayerPlayer.kt:89)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.WrappedPlayer.stop(WrappedPlayer.kt:185)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.WrappedPlayer.onCompletion(WrappedPlayer.kt:248)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.MediaPlayerPlayer.createMediaPlayer$lambda-5$lambda-1(MediaPlayerPlayer.kt:17)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.MediaPlayerPlayer.$r8$lambda$3fK1i48Yert5dbg2Q8ZiB5tiKHg(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.MediaPlayerPlayer$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onCompletion(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:3559)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
I/Process (28346): Sending signal. PID: 28346 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

I guess I somewhat messed up the resource management due the repeated execution. Therefore I guess the error lies somewhat in the API usage of `audioplayers.dart`?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the `ReleaseMode` to `release`. What I did was using `stop` that kept the resources in memory I guess and therefore cluttered the memory?